# select a row except all the other rows based on some condition psql

Tags: psql

Consider this scenario:

There is a table `T (name,habit)` where combination of name and habit is the primary key for the table `T`.

Suppose the data is as follows:

```
name | habit 
a1 | smoking
a1 | drinking
a2 | sleeping
a3 | jogging
a2 | jogging
a4 | sleeping
```

Now I want to select names which have all the habits as unique. Here clearly `a2,a3` and `a4` have habits in common so they should be filtered out.

So the output should be like

OUTPUT:

```
name
a1
```

My question:

How can I do this using `except` in psql?

Comment: you don't need `except` for it

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `except` for it:

```
t=# with a as (
  select *,count(1) over (partition by habit)
  from t
)
select distinct name
from a
where count = 1;
 name
------
 a1
(1 row)
```

schema:

```
t=# create table T (name text,habit text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 14.162 ms
t=# copy t from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> a1 | smoking
a1 | drinking
a2 | sleeping
a3 | jogging
a2 | jogging
a4 | sleeping>> >> >> >> >>
>> \.
COPY 6
Time: 3216.573 ms
```